# How to boot Kali Linux on a Mac without using Grub?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, unix

- I am trying to install Kali Linux on an external hard drive. I downloaded the `kali-linux-2022.1-live-amd64.iso` file and checked with `shasum -a 256 kali-linux-2022.1-live-amd64.iso`. I am using a 13" 2019 MacBook Pro running on Catalina. Everything works smoothly during the installation process until I get to the Grub Boot loader Installation part.
- I received the following errors during the installation:

“Executing ‘grub-install dummy’ failed. This is a fatal error.”

I press continue…

“No boot loader has been installed, either because you chose not to or because your specific architecture doesn’t support a boot loader yet. You will need to boot manually with the `/vmlinuz` kernel on partition `/dev/sdd3` and `root=/dev/sdd3 quiet` passed as a kernel argument."

- The installation then finishes and boots to Mac OS.
- Does anyone have a clue what this actually means and what can I do to make it work?
- Here is the output of
  `diskutil list`

[image]

For you reference:

- Linux installed in /dev/disk2
- USB stick containing Kali Linux (I used balenaEtcher for preparation) in /dev/disk3
- I followed the instructions at:
  https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-mac/

EDIT:

- I have tried installing rEFInd. Here is the output of
  `./refind-install`

[image]

Comment: Which instructions did you follow (add a link if possible)?

Comment: Math4biz: Which one of [these instructions](https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/) did you use? Did you try a grubless boot as the Kali installer suggested?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I used the instructions under "Creating a Bootable Kali USB Drive on macOS/OS X (Etcher)". Etcher seems to be the standard way.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried installing rEFInd but got an error. I posted the output above.

Comment: What is the name of the file downloaded from Kali?

Comment: @DavidAnderson That would be kali-linux-2022.1-live-amd64.iso. 
I did check with `shasum -a 256 kali-linux-2022.1-live-amd64.iso` that the file is indeed the correct one.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. Took over 5 hours to download from Kali. I really did not get back to your question until this morning.

Comment: math4biz: If my answer worked, then you might consider accepting the answer. This will put a green checkmark next to the answer. Other users will then know an answer was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated in your question that Grub (Grand Unified Boot Loader) was not installed and the Kali installer suggested to boot manually with the `/vmlinuz` kernel. This is referred to as a *Grubless boot*. The boot loader in the Mac firmware can do Grubless boots, if instructed to do so. However, you will need to use a different startup manager. [The rEFInd Boot Manager](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is a popular choice.

### Installing rEFInd

Below are the instructions for installing rEFInd version 0.13.2 to the external drive where Kali resides.

> Note: You do **not** have to disable SIP.

1. Download `refind-bin-0.13.2.zip` from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). By default, the download should automatically unzip to create the `refind-bin-0.13.2` folder in your `Downloads` folder.
2. Enter the commands given below.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk2s1
   ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.13.2/refind-install --usedefault /dev/disk2s1 
   bless --folder /tmp/refind_install/EFI/BOOT --label rEFInd
   diskutil unmount disk2s1
   ```

   The `refind-install` script has a bug where a `sed` command uses options compatible with Linux, but not macOS. Therefore, the script terminates early before making rEFInd the default to boot and unmounting the EFI volume (`/dev/disk2s1`) on the external drive. This bug goes back many versions of rEFInd and probably will not be fixed any time in the near future.

   Below is sample output from entering the above commands. Your output may differ, since the machine used had High Sierra installed instead of Catalina. The commands were entered in a Z shell.

   ```
   dmas-iMac% diskutil unmount disk2s1
   disk2s1 was already unmounted
   dmas-iMac% ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.13.2/refind-install --usedefault /dev/disk2s1 
   Not running as root; attempting to elevate privileges via sudo....
   Password:
   ShimSource is none
   Installing rEFInd on macOS....
   Installing rEFInd to the partition mounted at /tmp/refind_install
   Found suspected Linux partition(s); installing ext4fs driver.
   Installing driver for ext4 (ext4_x64.efi)
   Copied rEFInd binary files

   Copying sample configuration file as refind.conf; edit this file to configure
   rEFInd.

   sed: -i may not be used with stdin
   dmas-iMac% bless --folder /tmp/refind_install/EFI/BOOT --label rEFInd
   dmas-iMac% diskutil unmount disk2s1                                              
   Volume EFI on disk2s1 unmounted
   ```

### Using rEFInd to Boot Kali

The steps are given below.

1. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the option key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear.
2. Select to boot from the icon labeled `rEFInd`.
3. When the rEFInd screen appears, Select to boot from the Linux icon highlighted below. Since the machine used had High Sierra installed instead of Catalina, your selection of macOS related icons may be different.

   [image: refind screen]
4. When the Kali login screen shown below appears, login to Kali.

   [image: kali login]

Comment: Thank you so much, worked just like you said. Have a good one sir.